# Solr: Implementation example of CJK Tokenizer for Chinese Language

Tags: solr, cjk

We have a website in Chinese language using solr for search and looking for the best Chinese tokenizer. CJKTokenizer looks the best theoretically but I am unable to find an actual implementation anywhere. Everywhere I can see the CJKFilters(instead of Tokenizer) being implemented with some other tokenizers.

Can I directly  use something like:

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="org.apache.solr.analysis.CJKTokenizerFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Is there any CJKTokenizer implementation code I can refer of CJKTokenizer is deprecated and these are the only options?(Like this page says https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/cjk/CJKTokenizer.html)

Comment: can you try below <fieldType name="ja_ngram" class="solr.TextField" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="false" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.CJKBigramFilterFactory" outputUnigrams="true" />
    <filter class="solr.CJKWidthFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
 </fieldType>

Comment: There are some references to a HMM Chinese Tokenizer in the Solr documentation (https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_6/language-analysis.html#hmm-chinese-tokenizer) that might be worth looking into.